# How do you get a code to chr through a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code for cyphering.  When looking at my code, you can see that def `xor()` code, but I need it to work for several letters in a string, but it keeps saying that it cannot do that because there is more than one letter doing the `chr` function.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    #After the string to decode is input, the user needs to input a word that will or will not be in the string.
    stringtodecode = input("Message to Decode: ")                       
    key = input("Key Word: ")
    def encrypt(stringtodecode, key):
        encrypted = ''
        for character in stringtodecode:
            encrypted = encrypted + xor(character, key)
        return encrypted
    def decrypt(stringtodecode, key):
        return encrypt(stringtodecode, key)
    def xor(character, key):
        code = ord(character) ^ ord(key)
        character = chr(code)
        return character
    print(decrypt(stringtodecode, key))
```

I am getting a `TypeError`.

Comment: Can you either provide the whole program, or give us an example of a key and what data you are entering, along with what results you are getting vs what you are expecting?

Comment: if __name__=="__main__":
#After the string to decode is input, the user needs to input a word that will or will not be in the string.
 stringtodecode = input("Message to Decode: ")      key = input("Key Word: ")
 def encode(stringtodecode, key):
  encoded = ''
  for character in stringtodecode:
   encoded = encoded + xor(character, key)
  return encoded

Comment: Please don't post that as a comment; include the entire code in your question, and add those other items I mentioned to your question so we can help you :)

Comment: Your current `xor` works for a single character key. It's not clear what you expect to do with multiple characters in your key. Do you intend to use just one key letter per character in the input? How do you deal with a longer message than your key? Do the key letters cycle?

Comment: I am trying, when I try to do it, it prints on one line.  Any advice on how to get it properly set up?

Comment: I am trying to do a cycle.

Comment: This part of the code:         for character in stringtodecode:
            encrypted = encrypted + xor(character, key) should do that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cycle the characters of your key word, you can use `itertools.cycle` and `zip` to do it as part of your loop over the characters in the message:

```
import itertools  # put this up near the top of the file somewhere

for m_char, k_char in zip(stringtodecode, itertools.cycle(key)):
    encrypted = encrypted + xor(m_char, k_char)
```

Building a string by repeated concatenation will be inefficient if the string could get long (it's takes time proportional to the square of the output length), so you may want to use `str.join` on a generator expression (which will run in linear time):

```
encrypted = "".join(xor(m_char, k_char)
                    for m_char, k_char in zip(stringtodecode, itertools.cycle(key)))
```

Comment: I just fixed one typo (`stringtoencode` instead of `stringtodecode`), but other than that, everything works in my testing. I would note that your encryption scheme could result in printing out control characters in some cases, which is not really ideal (it may break your terminal), but if you pick your message and key carefully (I suggest one with only capitals and the other all lowercase), it should work.